# "Deployed to" vs "deployed on"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one of the following statements is correct:

> 1. I deployed something to the test server.
> 2. I deployed something on the test server.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would say it depends where you are deploying. Deploying "to" the test server implies a remote operation - HTTP / ssh / ftp, amongst others. Deploying "on" the test server implies that you are at the console/GUI of the server, whether it be physically (touching the keyboard and mouse) or virtually (VNC or similar application that acts on the server itself).

Comment: I considered mentioning this, but I didn't consider it a clear enough distinction. For instance, I'd put SSH in the class of *on*, not *to*. I guess *to* for me implies that the deployment consists (perhaps entirely) of a *transfer*, while *on* implies that any transfer has already taken place, and the deployment itself is a local operation such as running an application or unpacking an archive.

Comment: Hmm, yes, ssh would be an "on"; I think when I wrote my answer I was thinking scp, but ssh came out. If you look at it as two separate actions, then I would have to agree that deployment as you put it would always be a local operation. I generally view the process as one operation; part of the deployment is the transfer process itself, especially when the transfer process may even do some of, if not all of, the unpacking.

Answer (score 13):

Your examples require articles:

> I deployed something to *the* test server.
> I deployed something on *the* test server.

Otherwise, these two are exactly equivalent.